# Would a "reading-as-a-writer" tag be useful?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are at least a few questions concerning reading as a writer. Would it be useful to make (and apply) a [reading-as-a-writer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-as-a-writer) tag?

Example questions (from the first page of the search "reading is:question") might include:
[Taking notes while reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/taking-notes-while-reading?)
[Does reading books help writing skills?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/does-reading-books-help-writing-skills?)
[Best Practices To Learn By Reading?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7737/best-practices-to-learn-by-reading?)
[Can I be a good writer without reading a lot?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/can-i-be-a-good-writer-without-reading-a-lot?)
[How do I balance reading time with writing time?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/how-do-i-balance-reading-time-with-writing-time?)

A more general [reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading) tag could include questions like:
[Can I improve my beta reading skills to aid a close person's writings?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/can-i-improve-my-beta-reading-skills-to-aid-a-close-persons-writings?)

However, I think "reading as a critic/editor" (including self-criticism/editing) should be distinct from "reading in order to become a better writer", perhaps using a [critical-reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critical-reading) tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading) tag would be fine.

Since we are on writers.SE, this implies that we think, ask and answer about reading from a writer's perspective, so a [reading-as-a-writer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-as-a-writer) tag is as superfluous as a [writing-as-a-writer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-as-a-writer) tag (there are of course other kinds of writing, e.g. diary writing, note taking in school, doing homework, writing private letters, etc., none of which make you a writer and all of which differ from writing for publication as a writer does it). Of course, the tag explanation should make clear to the confused passer-by what we think of when we tag something as [reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading).

As for the [critical-reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critical-reading) tag, this is [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) and needs no extra tag (because how else are you going to criticize, if you don't read it first). But of course we need a [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) tag (with the explanation that this labels questions about *how to* critique, not *asking for* a critique).

#### tl;dr

**+** [reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading)
**-** [reading-as-a-writer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-as-a-writer)
**+** [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique) or [criticize](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticize) or [review](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review)
**-** [critical-reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critical-reading)